# Opening new tab and loading current tab at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

My employer ask me to create a function that upon click, it open a new site at new tab, but at the same time the current page finishes loading or load to other page. I'm afraid I only have pseudocode to show, as I think it's a technical problem, not a coding one.

```
protected void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
//Some logics with some post and get process.

//generate URL

//Redirect to an external page in a new tab.
//At the same time current page undergo UI changes or redirecting to other page.}
```

However, the moment the page redirect to an external page, it no longer read anything below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as opening a new windows with JavaScript and refreshing the current one in the same function.

```
<button onclick="OpenAndReload()">Open & Reload</button>

<script>
    function OpenAndReload() {
        window.open('https://www.google.nl');
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

If you want to do this from code behind you will only need the `window.open` since the PostBack will reload the page anyway.

```
protected void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //your code

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('https://www.google.nl');", true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. It seems Response.Redirect totally stops everything, even this script. So I had to find another way around by adding a script to redirect to new page. Your answer helped me into the right direction.